# Reaching Form Instances

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a level editor application designed in a MDI project. The application has two main view modes, the `WorldEditor` mode and `ObjectEditor` mode. Depending on the mode, I want a separate property window to show a property setup specific for the current mode.

I've thought of using the `Activated` event, and from that event tell the property form to load the appropriate setup. I need to reach the `PropertyForm` from within the `World` or `Object` Form class to accomplish this. This is where I'm stuck.

I believe I should be able to solve this by declaring the `PropertyForm` class as static. Since I only use one of it's types at a time, I want to be able to reach it globally. However declaring a form class as `static` gives me compiler errors. I'm doing it wrong, if it's even possible.

How can I reach and search for different forms that are active in the application?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a singleton, not a static class.

Without much loss of performance you can create different objects of PropertyForm - one for each type of 'view' you have. You can add a parametrized constructor - should take an object that has the details specific to each view. This will allow you to create the PropertyForm specific for each view.

If you really want to have just one copy of the PropertyForm, then a simpler approach is to hide the form. In the "show" event handler you can customize it per the current view. Consider the singleton approach as the last.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your MDI parent form (which knows which of the MDI child windows is active) should hold a reference to the Property form. Add an event handler to each created child window's Activated event, using a function in your parent form that uses the information from the activated child window to set up the Property form correctly.

Sesh's answer regarding a Singleton may apply as well, though that's really another question.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get what you need from the `sender` parameter in the `Activated` event handler.